# Python: iteration across data frames

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, iteration

I´m new on python and I need a little help with my code in order to achieve an iteration across different data frames with the same columns.

My data frame looks like this:

```
Date, Product, Value1, Value2
13-3-2020, A, 10, 15
13-4-2020, A, 11, 26
13-5-2020, A, 14, 14
2-2-2018, B, 10, 15
18-2-2018, B, 11, 26
5-4-2018, B, 14, 14
5-5-2018, B, 12, 12
```

I created a list of data frames grouping by product:

```
groups = list(df.groupby('Product'))
```

And then I want to fill each data frame with the first day of the month between the first and last date. Unfortunately I am just having the last product as an output, as a separate data-frame.

I tried this code:

```
for g, grp in groups:
    month_grp = pd.Series(pd.date_range(start=min(grp['Date']), end=max(grp['Date']), freq='MS'), name="Date").to_frame()
    grp = grp.append(month_grp, ignore_index=True)
    grp = grp.sort_values(by='Date').reset_index(drop=True)

    print(grp)

        Date Product  Value1  Value2
0 2018-02-02       B    10.0    15.0
1 2018-02-18       B    11.0    26.0
2 2018-03-01     NaN     NaN     NaN
3 2018-04-01     NaN     NaN     NaN
4 2018-05-01     NaN     NaN     NaN
5 2018-05-04       B    14.0    14.0
6 2018-05-05       B    12.0    12.0
```

The solution I´m looking for it´s an iteration over each Product, dataframe. And ideally saving this result in the groups list of data frames, because I´m performing more calculations afterwards.

Any help it´s appreciate it. Even if it´s a new approach on how to handle this data frame by groups and it´s not trough `pandas`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a sample of your expected output

Comment: The `grp` variable resets itself with the `for` statement. In the first iteration of the `for` loop, `grp` will have the group of product A and you are appending more rows to it. In the second pass, `grp` is assigned the group of product B  and that's why you are only getting the last `grp`. It is better to assign it to a new df and then group them again.

Comment: thanks your advice I was able to achieve what I wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution thanks to davidbilla suggestion. I created a new df where I append the results from the loop.

```
data = StringIO("""\Date, Product, Value1, Value2""")
dff = pd.read_table(data, sep=', ', parse_dates=[0])

for g, grp in groups:
    month_grp = pd.Series(pd.date_range(start=min(grp['Date']),end=max(grp['Date']), freq='MS'), name="Date").to_frame()
grp = grp.append(month_grp, ignore_index=True)
grp = grp.sort_values(by='Date').reset_index(drop=True)
dff = dff.append(grp)
```